# Python Minidom Parsing File Objects

Tags: python, xml, parsing, minidom

I wrote a code using minidom which takes an `xml` script, opens it as a file object and then parses that file object. Not only that, but I want the script to open multiple files that are all contained in a folder, and parse each one individually.

An example of the `xml` script is:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Data>
  <data1>1</data1>
  <data2>2</data2>
  <data3>3</data3>
  <Sub_data>
    <sub_data1>0.1111111111111</sub_data1>
    <sub_data2>0.2222222222222</sub_data2>
    ... and so on.
```

i.e., it's pretty standard.

Now, my code looks like this:

```
import os
import io
from xml.dom import minidom

#folder where xml files are located
indir = '/foo/bar/docs/'

    masterlist = []

    for root, dirs, filenames in os.walk(indir):
      for f in filenames:
        row = []
        fsock = io.open(indir + f, mode = 'rt', encoding = 'cp1252')
        xmldoc = minidom.parse(fsock)
        ...
```

and the error I am getting is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last): File "kgp_2.py", line 34, in
<module> xmldoc = minidom.parse(fsock) File
"/usr/lib/python2.7/xml/dom/minidom.py", line 1918, in parse return
expatbuilder.parse(file) File
"/usr/lib/python2.7/xml/dom/expatbuilder.py", line 928, in parse
result = builder.parseFile(file) File
"/usr/lib/python2.7/xml/dom/expatbuilder.py", line 211, in parseFile
parser.Parse("", True) xml.parsers.expat.ExpatError: no element found:
line 203, column 1381
```

Now, when I make the change:

```
fsock = io.open(indir + filenames[0], mode = 'rt', encoding = 'cp1252')
```

this works fine, that is, it opens the first file in the folder; but I want to parse all the files in the folder. When I do a loop like:

```
m = 0
... in loop:
fsock = io.open(indir + filenames[m], mode = 'rt', encoding = 'cp1252')
...
m = m+1
```

I get the original error.

The reason I am using the io library instead of the usual file open function is that a previous stack overflow article recommended it. Using:

```
fsock = open(indir + filenames[0])
```

like before, gets no error, but:

```
fsock = open(indir + f)
```

or

```
#with a loop over m, like above
fsock = open(infir + filenames[m])
```

get the same error as above.

A strange problem. When I print the filenames they are correct. And they **are** being opened, there's no error there. It's the parser that just won't parse the object files, even with `filenames[m]` where `m = 0`, surely this should be no problem?

EDIT:
[Parsing document with python minidom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3625897/parsing-document-with-python-minidom)

in this post they had a similar problem, the resolution was to use

```
    xmldoc.seek(0)
```

however, for me this returns

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "kgp_2.py", line 45, in <module>
xmldoc.seek(0)
AttributeError: Document instance has no attribute 'seek'
```

**EDIT 2: THIS HAS BEEN RESOLVED. IT WAS A CASE OF A CORRUPTED INPUT XML FILE.**

Comment: Have you checked the content of the variable `f`/`f[m]`/`filename[m]`, etc. in each iteration?

Comment: Hi, I have "When I print the filenames (that would be the variable f) they are correct." (I have also printed filename[m] and they are correct) If there was a problem there, I don't think open(f) would work, which it does.

Comment: Try using the standard `os.path.join()` ([doc](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.join)) to join indir and the file.

Comment: I gave that a shot and I'm getting the same error

Comment: Are you sure the XML data contained in *all* XML files is correct? Perhaps one is empty an you have to handle such Exception. Anyhow I recommend you to use `xml.etree` ([doc](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html)).

Comment: I tried it on a subset of two xml files which parsed themselves when handled separately and it worked fine. So it looks like there's an xml file in the folder which is empty or corrupted, as you suggested. Thank you very much!

Comment: May you please accep my answer as the good one. I appreciate!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure the XML data contained in all XML files is correct? Perhaps one is empty an you have to handle such Exception. Anyhow I recommend you to use `xml.etree` [doc](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html).